# Jump Animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, game-physics

My newest Hobby Project is a very simple Jump'n'Run Game using JavaScript. I already wrote some code (with the help of a tutorial at lostdecadegames) and read everything about the GameLoop.

```
var start = true;

// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1200;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var jumping = false;
var gravity = 1.5;
var pressed = true;


// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "monster.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed_x: 50,
    speed_y_up: 50,
    speed_y_down: 50, // movement in pixels per second
    velocity_x: 50,
    velocity_y: 50
};

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);


// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if(38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        jumping = true;
        //hero.y -= hero.speed_y_up * modifier;
    }   
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed_y_down * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed_x * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed_x * modifier;
    }

};


// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (heroReady) {
        if(hero.y > 0 && hero.y < 480 && hero.x <= -32)
            {
            hero.x = hero.x + 1232;
            ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
            }
        else if(hero.y > 0 && hero.y < 480 && hero.x >= 1200)
            {
            hero.x = hero.x - 1232;
            ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
            }
        else if(jumping)
            {
            ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y-100);
            jumping = false;
            }
        else ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }

    if (monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }


};


// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 500);
    render();

    then = now;
};

// Starting the game!
reset();
var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
```

As you can see, I already added a fix gravity var and some speed vars. The Hero moves very smooth, so this is no problem. 
I have 2 problems with the jump-Animation:

1. The Hero stays in the air, when the Up-Key is keep being pressed. I tried to fix this with some boolean vars, but I couldn't figure it out how to get the Hero down again.
2. Right now, I implemented a "dirty hack" which causes the Hero to be repainted 50px higher, but I want a smooth Jump, so that the Hero gets slower while going up and speeds up while falling. I looked up so many Tutorials and so much Example Code, but I'm too stupid to figure it out, how I get my desired Animation.

Hope you guys can give me some advice for my problem (I'm not asking for the final code, I just need some tips).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand exactly what the if statements inside of `if (heroReady)` are doing because the numbers don't mean anything to me, but it seems to me like your problem is in there.

First of all, it seems to me like `jumping` should the first condition checked. If one of the first conditions is true, then it doesn't matter whether or not he's jumping. I can't easily tell when each condition is true, though, so I'm going to assume that when the player is holding up,

```
else if(jumping)
{
    ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y-100);
    jumping = false;
}
```

gets executed like normal.

Now, assuming that, I think your issue is that `jumping` is determined solely by whether or not the player is holding up, because as soon as `jumping` is true, it becomes false. This is incorrect.

Jumping should be set to true when the player presses the up key, but it should be set to false when they remove it. It should be set to false when the animation hits the ground.

Another issue that you have is the fact that you aren't actually using the hero's attributes to render its jumping location, you're simply offsetting it. Perhaps that is just your workaround until the problem is solved, but it makes it hard to tell when the character hits the ground, because you can't start lower the character (increasing the y value) after they jump, since you never raised them by decreasing the y value.

So how do we fix this?

Here are my recommendations. You might find more elegant ways to do it by the time you're done due to refactoring, but the way you have it set up right now I think it will work fine:

- Set `jumping` as soon as they press up, like you're doing, but only if `jumping == false`, because presumably your hero can't do mid-air jumps.
- Immediately after you set `jumping` (and inside the same if statement), update their velocity.
- In your update section, add another if for whether or not the player is jumping, *regardless of whether or not they are pressing any keys*. If they are, decrease their momentum based on gravity. Then, add a check for if their momentum is *the opposite of how much you increase it when they start jumping*. In other words, check if they are moving down at exactly the same rate they were moving up when they started jump. This happens at exactly the y-coordinate that they began the jump from. (This is more reliable that just checking their position, because it will work from multiple y-locations.) The alternative would be to store a variable with the y-coordinate they were at when they jumped. Either way, if their jump has ended, set jumping to false.
- Since you're updating their coordinates based on jumping, in your render function, you can eliminate any jumping logic and just draw the image based on the coordinates.

Does that help at all?

Comment: I will try this right now. Thank you, hope this will work out.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, and came up with a similar solution (i.e. storing the starting position in a variable) but was concerned that jumping again would just over-ride the starting pos variable. I forgot that it wouldn't because as long as the current pos is higher than the starting pos you couldn't jump... -- problem with this is that it doesn't scale to being able to land on anything, i.e. if you could jump onto things, you could then not jump while on them, because your pos would still be too high. So I guess this would be kind of a hack in that sense. So what I'm asking:

Comment: What's the best way to update the jumping variable to false?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. - Short answer: that depends on what kind of function you're using to jump in the first place. I was using a combination of setInterval, setTimeout and clearInterval (i.e. do stuff repeatedly until the time's up, then clear) - so adding a turning jumping to false at the end was easy. just needed to add jumping true to the part that called it, like OP did. Thanks you two! :)